# How to get data tables to show uppercase in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't figure how to get data table to show the letters uppercase in the table. I need name and vendor to be upper case. I did add the  `onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"` to the add form but when I hit submit the table shows the data in all lowercase. So I figured I could force the data tables to show it in uppercase. I posted partial code from my controller. Any helped would be appreciated.

```
public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->visitor_log_list->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $visitor_log_list) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $visitor_log_list->date;
            $row[] = $visitor_log_list->name;
            $row[] = $visitor_log_list->vendor;
            $row[] = $visitor_log_list->department;
            $row[] = $visitor_log_list->contact_person;
            $row[] = $visitor_log_list->expected_arrival_time;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-link " href="javascript:void()" title="Edit" onclick="edit_visitor_log('."'".$visitor_log_list->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm text-warning" href="javascript:void()" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_visitor_log('."'".$visitor_log_list->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->visitor_log_list->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->visitor_log_list->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the strings in `strtoupper()`:

```
<?php
    public function ajax_list() {
        $list = $this->visitor_log_list->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no   = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $visitor_log_list) {
            $no++;
            $row    = array();
            $row[]  = $visitor_log_list->date;
            $row[]  = strtoupper($visitor_log_list->name);
            $row[]  = strtoupper($visitor_log_list->vendor);
            $row[]  = $visitor_log_list->department;
            $row[]  = $visitor_log_list->contact_person;
            $row[]  = $visitor_log_list->expected_arrival_time;
            //add html for action
            $row[]  = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-link " href="javascript:void()" title="Edit" onclick="edit_visitor_log(' . "'" . $visitor_log_list->id . "'" . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm text-warning" href="javascript:void()" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_visitor_log(' . "'" . $visitor_log_list->id . "'" . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->visitor_log_list->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->visitor_log_list->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I will except your answere in 9 min

Comment: @Donny If my answer helped you, be sure to hit the little check mark by the arrows on the left side - You can do that for any question you ask for any answer that helped you :)

Comment: will do it says I can do it in 3 min

Comment: @Donny Hi Donny. I noticed you still haven't accepted the answer, if you could please accept that when you get a chance if I helped you.